# mvc3 and linq - creating a ViewModel

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I need to do two/three independent queries and load into the same viewmodel and pass it to the view.

here is what I am doing, but it doesnt even compile, please take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong.. Thanks

UserViewModel class has 2 parameters, title, option

e.g.

```
UserViewModel user= new UserViewModel ();

    var model = (from a in db.Table1
     where string.Equals(a.username, "bob")
    select user
    {   user.Title = a.Title,
        user.option = 1
    });
```

Second query

```
    model = (from b in db.Table2
             where string.Equals(b.username, "bob")
             select user
             {
                 user.Title= b.Title,
                 user.option= 2
             });

var list = model.ToList();
return View("List",list);
```

This is simple queries and I know I can now put them into 1 query, but in the future It will be completely independent and I need to know how to do two/three queries and put them into one viewmodel. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var user = db.Table1
     .Where(m => m.username == "bob")
     .Select(x => new UserViewModel 
         {
            Title = x.Title,
            Option = 1
         })
      .Union(
           db.Table2
      .Where(m => m.username == "bob")
      .Select(x => new UserViewModel
        {
           Title = x.Title,
           option = 2
        })
      ).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks so much! Could you plz also tell me how would you pass 2 separate models to a view (if the models were different)? and if know if there are any cons of doing it.

Comment: You can pass one model as the "View's model" and the other in a ViewBag. But it would be better to create a new class (ViewModel) with all the classes you need in your view, and pass that class to your View.